# google alerts RSS feed on homepage feed module

Tags: 7, feeds

I am trying to import a google alert, which I have chosen to be a feed, onto the homepage of a drupal site I am creating.

The goal is to be able to automatically display the results of the rss feed but also to not publish everything right away as I would like to potentially screen the results before they are posted.

I just want to link to the articles respective webpages not necessarily store them as articles within our own drupal site.

I am trying out the module feeds http://drupal.org/node/622696

It might be a lot more than what I need but maybe the only available module. If you know of something better that suits my needs let me know.

I am new to drupal and this module required me to also install:

CTools
Job Scheduler

both of those were listed in the readme, but when I went to the modules admin page I was told I was missing:

features
views

So I went ahead and installed those as well. Is it normal that I had to install those even though they weren't included in the readme at all?

In any case.. I was able to import a feed but it seems to store all rss feed items as articles.

I also do not see any settings for setting how many posts should be visible, how much content should be shown right away (just want headlines). Although I may need to dig deeper into the code to change this stuff.

I guess what I am really asking is if there is a better/easier way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need Features and Views if you enable the Feeds News module. I think you can import from an RSS feed without that (by changing the Fetcher and Parser settings). However, IIRC, the Feeds News module does automatically create a View interface for you that manages all the feed items from a specific source so it can be handy.

Your setup sounds similar to one I implemented in D6, and it works well for the client. Once the items are imported, use Views to customize the output: a Views block can be configured to show the desired number of posts, titles as links, etc.

You may also want to implement [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to manage the publishing of the feed items from your administrative page.